# WinSCP script : System cannot find the path specified

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I try to SFTP file to remote server using winSCP .bat script but the script keep prompt "The system cannot find the path specified." And winscp will open new session tab to other location.

File location : \pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test

File destination : /cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in

```
@echo off

echo %date%

set month=%date:~0,2%
echo month=%date:~0,2%

set day=%date:~3,2%
echo day=%date:~3,2%

set year=%date:~6,4%
echo year=%date:~6,4%


set LookForFile="\\pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test\*.*"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO Eftipi
echo %time% : The file is not ready yet. Wait 5seconds


TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul
GOTO CheckForFile


:Eftipi
echo.
echo start SFTP
echo Transfering QA file from 'Pbil' folder to QA serve location:(cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in)
echo Start time : %date% %time%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" sftp://mebills:pass****@astrobill.com.my/ -hostkey="ecdsa-sha2********"
copy "\\pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test" "/cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in"
echo End time : %date% %time%
pause
```

Comment: `WinSCP` offers scripting interface, see [Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#example).

Comment: Your question code is not a [mcve] because you have not included the code which determines one of the branches of the path, i.e. `%year%`. additionally, we have no idea if, at the time of running, the network location is available to the end user, perhaps using `PushD "\\pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test"` would be a more sensible option. Additionally, you state `file` location, but your `copy` command will be copying `all files` in the top level of a directory named `Test`; can you please clarify the task..

Comment: Hi @Compo, i just update my full script. What im trying to do is, to Copy all file from `Test` to remote server which is `mebills` in this location `/cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in`

Comment: Did any files get copied? does the end user have full permissions on every file within the `Test` directory? Did you try using `PushD`, as advised? Is the code being run on exactly the same PC with the same user settings?

Comment: No file copy even if i try using `PushD`. It seem like the script unable to locate the destination `/cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in`. end user have permissions to both `pbil` and `mebills`. and using the same settings.

Comment: What is the complete error message? It's important to know which file winscp is claiming it can't find.

Comment: I found the solution after trying multiple code. i replace `:Eftipi` content to `:Eftipi
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://mebills:password@astrobill.com.my/ -hostkey=""ecdsa-sha2-******""" ^
    "put ""\\pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test"" "/cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in" " ^
 "exit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace :Eftipi content to

```
:Eftipi
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://mebills:password@astrobill.com.my/ -hostkey=""ecdsa-sha2-*****=""" ^
    "put ""\\pbilsr01\ACCESS BILLING\%year%\BMD Bill QA\Jun\Test"" "/cygdrive/d/VB_SHARE/astroQA/AFP/in" " ^
    "exit"
```